# Calculate sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\ln n}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

What is the exact sum of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\ln n}{n}$$

Comment: Why do you think there is a simpler way to write this number?

Comment: According to Mathematica, $\gamma\log 2-(\log2)^2/2\approx .1599$.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Define 
 $$\eta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}$$
convergent $\Re(s)>0$, but we shall only use $\eta(s)$ for $\Re(s)>1$. 
Then the quantity of interest is
$$
   -\lim_{s \downarrow 1} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \eta(s)
$$
Now, for $\Re(s)>1$ we can evaluate $\eta(s)$ as follows:
$$
    \eta(s) + \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^s} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s} = 2 \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2m)^s} = 2^{1-s} \zeta(s)
$$
Hence
$$
   \eta(s) = \zeta(s) \left(2^{1-s} - 1 \right)
$$
Keeping in mind that [Riemann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) has a pole at $s=1$, $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1} + \gamma + \mathcal{o}(1)$, where $\gamma$ denotes the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) we arrive at:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   -\lim_{s \downarrow 1} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \eta(s) &=& \lim_{s \downarrow 1} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \zeta(s) \left(1-2^{1-s} \right) \\ &=& \lim_{s \downarrow 1} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \left( \frac{1}{s-1} + \gamma + \mathcal{o}(1) \right) \left(\log(2) (s-1) - \frac{\log^2(2)}{2} (s-1)^2 +  \mathcal{o}\left((s-1)^2\right)  \right) \\ &=& -\frac{1}{2} \log^2(2) + \log(2) \gamma 
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: similar to a key step in euler's proof of the infinitude of primes

Answer (score 19):

$$\begin{eqnarray}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^k\frac{\log(k)}{k} &=& -\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\log(k)}{k} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\log(2k)}{k}\\
&=& \log(2)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} -\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\log(n+k)}{n+k}\\
&=& \log(2)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} -\frac{\log(n)}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}- \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(1+\frac{k}{n})}{1+\frac{k}{n}}\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Now we can recognize two Riemann sums:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}=\int_1^2\frac{dt}{t} + O(\frac{1}{n}) = \log(2)+O(\frac{1}{n})$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(1+\frac{k}{n})}{1+\frac{k}{n}} =\int_1^2\frac{\log(t)}{t}dt = \frac{1}{2}\log(2)^2.$$

Combining all this gives

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{\log(k)}{k}&=&-\frac{1}{2}\log(2)^2+\log(2) \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} -\log(n)\right)\\
&=& -\frac{1}{2}\log(2)^2+\log(2)\,\gamma.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: Beautiful solution (+1)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
S_{n} &:= \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{\ln k}{k} \\
(-1)^k &\frac{\ln k}{k} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{\ln k}{k} &= \lim_{n\to+\infty}S_{2n}.
\end{align*}

\text{Now:}

\begin{align*}
S_{2n} &= \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln2k}{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln(2k-1)}{2k-1} \\
&= \frac{\ln2}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln k}{k}-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\ln k}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln2k}{2k}\right) \\
&= \ln2H_{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln k}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\ln k}{k} \\
&= \ln2H_{n}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln(n+k)}{n+k} \\
&= \ln2H_{n}-\sum_{k=1} ^{n}\frac{\ln n+\ln(1+k/n)}{n+k} \\
&= \ln2H_{n}-\ln n(H_{2n}-H_{n})-\frac{ 1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln(1+k/n)}{1+k/n} \\
&= H_{n}\ln(2n)-H_{2n}\ln n-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln(1+k/ n)}{1+k/n}\stackrel{H_{n}=\ln n+\gamma+\mathcal O(1/n)}{=}\gamma\ln2+\mathcal O(1/n)-\frac {1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln(1+k/n)}{1+k/n} \\
&\to\gamma\ln2-\int_{0}^ {1}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx \\
&=\gamma\ln2-\frac{\ln^22}{2}.
\end{align*}